# Displaying a list like a p:selectOneMenu in a page wise manner

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I'm trying to manage a `<p:selectOneMenu>` drop-down to show a list of 12000 records; I'm searching for a smart component within "paginate" my results and dynamic load on scrolling.
Can someone help me?
I'm using Primefaces 3.5

Thanks
Davide

Comment: PrimeFaces has a p:autoComplete for the purpose.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC ; is there a way to paginate the result list? for example, show 100 records and update the list when scrolling down

Comment: Do you really think, that this is very usefull for the user? i dont think is the right way to do